How to expose functions from decrypted code in PHP extensions
I am  trying to secure my laravel project, or at least the most critical parts  of it. I am planning to  make it a  SaaS but it will take me sometime so I was going to just encrypt most of the project. I learned about php extensions and  how to build one using C++ and  crypto++ for encryption and decryption. I also made a simple encryption tool using the same library.
It took me like a week to setup the extension with C++ and include all the libraries and now it's running. I wrote the decryption logic that will get the php decrypted code and then execute it. All of this with a simple function  to be called in a  .php file (loader_decrypt(encrypted_file_path)); but as always, nothing works  the way I  want :)  the execution  of the  php code is successful, but I  don't want it to be executed,  I want  the functions and classes inside that file to be availabe, for example:
Controller (to be encrypted):
namespace App\\Http\\Controllers;

class Controller
{

public function hello() {
    echo "hello";
}

}

Controller (will call a function from encrypted Controller):
<?php
// Ensure the loader extension is loaded
if (!extension_loaded('loader')) {
    die('The loader extension is not loaded.');
}

// Path to your encrypted file
$encryptedFilePath = 'Controller.enc';

// Execute the encrypted file
if (loader_decrypt($encryptedFilePath)) {
    echo "Decryption and execution were successful.";

    // Now you can use the Controller class
    $controller = new Controller();
    $controller->hello();
} else {
    echo "Decryption or execution failed.";
}
?>

when add the extension to my php.ini and trying php Controller.php, it prints:
Decryption and execution were successful. PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Controller" not found in /home/.../Desktop/Controller.php:15
this is what I mean by executing the file and not exposing its content. worth to note that i do NOT want anyone, even someone with server access to see my source code for the encrypted Controller. How can I do that ?
bool decryptAndExecuteFile(const std::string& filePath) {
    std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Unable to open file." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Read IV from the file
    SecByteBlock iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(iv.data()), iv.size());

    // Read the rest of the file as ciphertext
    std::string ciphertext((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    file.close();

    // Extract key from the ciphertext
    std::string key = extractKeyAndCleanCiphertext(ciphertext);

    // Ensure key size is correct
    if (key.size() != AES_KEYLENGTH) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Key length is incorrect." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Decrypt the data
    std::string decryptedContent = decryptData(ciphertext, key, std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(iv.data()), iv.size()));

    if (decryptedContent.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Decryption failed!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Debugging: Write decrypted content to a file for inspection
    std::ofstream debugFile("decrypted_debug.php");
    debugFile << decryptedContent;
    debugFile.close();

    // Check for unexpected characters and clean the content
    std::string cleanContent;
    for (char c : decryptedContent) {
        if (std::isprint(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)) || std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))) {
        cleanContent += c;
    }
}

    // Debugging: Print length and first few characters of cleaned content
    std::cout << "Cleaned content length: " << cleanContent.size() << std::endl;

     // Check if the content starts with "<?php"
    if (cleanContent.find("<?php") != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Decrypted content does not start with '<?php'." << std::endl;
    }

    // Convert cleaned content to zend_string
    zend_string *php_code = zend_string_init(cleanContent.c_str(), cleanContent.length(), 0);
    int result = zend_eval_string(ZSTR_VAL(php_code), nullptr, "Decrypted PHP Code");
    zend_string_release(php_code);

    if (result == FAILURE) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to execute decrypted PHP code." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

this is the function that is responsible for decrypting and executing of the php code.  Another problem that I do not know for sure what will happen is that if I found a solution for this problem, will it work with laravel ? I hope to learn more about php extensions and how to make them even more effective.
EDIT
Another thing. Other Controllers extend from  this controller class. how will this work because I tried to use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; but it still couldn't find the Controller class.
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Management;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MemberCourseDetailsController extends Controller
{
   public function  sayHelloFromController() {
        $this->hello();
   }
}


Your PHP code is not correct and should throw a parse error because of the double backslashes: https://3v4l.org/MrepF

Additionally, you instantiate Controller instead of \App\Http\Controllers\Controller.

sometimes I wonder how  am I a software developer XD. you are correct @Olivier it  now works but there is another problem. Other controllers actually extends from this Controller that loads and decrypts the encrypted controller. I  will edit  the question to make it more reproducible

I tried somethig which is to use require_once "path/to/Controller.php"; and it worked but just curious if there is another way @Olivier

I guess you will need to write your own autoload.

no actually laravel handled the rest, I was adding require_once in each Controller that extends from that Controller but discovered that I donn't need to. thx @Olivier
